# Java DateTimeFormatter for time zone with an optional colon separator?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I'm trying to build a DateTimeFormatter that can accepts offset with colon or offset without colon.

Is there a way to pass this test :

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[X]");
dateTimeFormatter.parse("2015-01-28T10:21:44+0100"); // OK
dateTimeFormatter.parse("2015-01-28T10:21:44+01:00"); // KO
```

Comment: The colon you consider to be optional is fixed part of the zone offset part. You can only choose between pattern letters X (without colon) or XXX (with colon). That means the whole zone offset is optional, not just the colon inside.

Comment: I agree, it should work. But when I use [X] it expects an offset without a colon and when I use [XXX] it expects an offset with a colon. I can't use both together.

Comment: According the Javadoc: with symbol X theses examples are given : Z; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;

Comment: Please read the javadoc-section "Offset X and x". It precisely describes which count of letters X,x is associated with which format representation. So we have: XX (without colon) and XXX (with colon). X (without colon) makes the minute part optional.

Comment: i'm getting 
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-01-28T10:21:44+01:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 22
under openjdk version "1.8.0_312"

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[XXX][X]` seems to work.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[XXX][X]");
dateTimeFormatter.parse("2015-01-28T10:21:44+0100");
dateTimeFormatter.parse("2015-01-28T10:21:44+01:00");
```

Comment: Yeah, it works! I tried [X][XXX] (not works) but not [XXX][X]. Thanks!

Comment: One exotic aspect: If the input contains TWO offsets then this might be parsed, too.

Answer (score 36):

Here is the ultimate pattern matching for pretty everything looking like an ISO string date !

```
"[yyyyMMdd][yyyy-MM-dd][yyyy-DDD]['T'[HHmmss][HHmm][HH:mm:ss][HH:mm][.SSSSSSSSS][.SSSSSS][.SSS][.SS][.S]][OOOO][O][z][XXXXX][XXXX]['['VV']']"
```

It works for the following list of tests except for the two in comments but I still don't know why...

```
    ZonedDateTime dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993+02:00:00[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993+02:00[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993+020000[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993+0200[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993+0000[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993Z[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993GMT+1[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993UTC[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993PST[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993[Europe/Paris]");

    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08+02:00[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08+020000[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08+0200[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08+0000[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08Z[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08GMT+1[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08UTC[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08PST[Europe/Paris]");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08[Europe/Paris]");

    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993+02:00:00");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993+02:00");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993+020000");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993+0200");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993+0000");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993Z");
    //dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993GMT+1");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993UTC");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993PST");

    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.993");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.000993");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08.000000993");

    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08+02:00:00");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08+02:00");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08+020000");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08+0200");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08+0000");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08Z");
    //dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08GMT+1");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08UTC");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08PST");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27T16:36:08");

    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-100T16:36:08Z");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-100T16:36.1Z");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("2016-10-27");

    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("20161223T163608");
    dt = DateTimeUtils.parse("20161223T1636");
```

And the parse method itself :

```
public static ZonedDateTime parse(CharSequence text) {
    TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = LOOSE_ISO_DATE_TIME_ZONE_PARSER.parseBest(text, ZonedDateTime::from, LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
    if (temporalAccessor instanceof ZonedDateTime) {
        return ((ZonedDateTime) temporalAccessor);
    }
    if (temporalAccessor instanceof LocalDateTime) {
        return ((LocalDateTime) temporalAccessor).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
    return ((LocalDate) temporalAccessor).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming it doesn't work for the ones in comment because you haven't catered for the "+1" after GMT. Granted, I don't recognize those expressions, but it seems there is no catering for the "+"-sign anywhere?

Comment: It is supposed to recognize the GMT+1 as a whole, as it does for 2016-10-27T16:36:08.993GMT+1[Europe/Paris] though.

Comment: Okay - Europe/Paris ends with text/the caret, though, while the ones not working ends with "+1" - I might be something there :)

Comment: ALMOST PERFECT, BUT,  when offset comes without a colon, the parse does not end with error, but the offset is not recognized, here the output for "2016-10-27T16:36:08.993+020000"  ==> 2016-10-27T16:36:08.993Z, I guess this is a parser problem, investigating a bit more.

Comment: Here is [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-) document. You can get that what's the mean of `XXXX` or `VV`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippeB.

Comment: 2016-10-27T16:36:08.993Z , unable to parse this format. Any solutions?@PhilippeB. @tonio